# Excel VBA Gathering Names from a Schedule of People Working Today

Tags: vba, excel

Even though I thought this would be a common question, I have searched and can't seem to find an answer.

I have a work schedule and I'd like to search the today's date and return all the names of those who are scheduled to work today. I built a code that works but it takes a long time to complete and is not 100% effective every time its run. I am sure there must be a better and faster way to do this but I have not yet been able to find one. I have it broken apart into two different codes. The first one finds the column where today's date is located and the second one gathers the names and places them onto the next sheet.

**Here's the First Sub:**

```
Sub GetDateRow_()
'//////Finds the row that has today's date and returns the value of that row to cell C34\\\\\\

Dim SearchMe As Integer

SearchMe = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C33")

    Set FindMe = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:AD5").Find(What:=SearchMe, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False)

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C34").Value = Cells(1, FindMe.Column)
End Sub
```

**And the Second Sub:**

```
Sub CopyScheduledToList()
'//////Searches Today's day Column from the schedule given by GetDateRow Sub & assimbles \\\\\\\
'//////      the names of those who are scheduled to work today to a list on Page 2      \\\\\\\

Dim Ccount As Integer
Dim lngLoop As Long
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim dShift As String
Dim cShift As String

Ccount = 1
dShift = "A63"
cShift = "TLA"


RowCount = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C34").Value
 lngLoop = 1

  For lngLoop = 1 To Rows.count
    If Cells(lngLoop, RowCount).Value = cShift Then Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 4).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngLoop, 1).Value
'////// Get's the Team Leader and places name into column D on Page 2
    If Cells(lngLoop, RowCount).Value = dShift Then Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ccount, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngLoop, 1).Value
    If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Ccount).Value <> "" Then Ccount = Ccount + 1
'////// Places the name from the working list onto page 2 and adds a count so the next value found
'////// will go to the next empty row on Sheet 2
  Next lngLoop

End Sub
```

Again, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ignore my previous comment (I mixed up your row counter and column counter) - it should have said ... The reason it takes so long is that you are processing over 1 million cells when you loop from `1 To Rows.Count`.  At a minimum, change `For lngLoop = 1 To Rows.count` to `For lngLoop = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, RowCount).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Thanks YowE3K! That did make it much faster! However, it's not working 100% of the time still. If I clear sheet2 or have the fields selected on sheet2, it won't work

Comment: That will almost certainly be due to the unqualified `Cells` references (i.e. the ones where you don't specify which sheet you are referring to).  I'll try to write an answer that gets around that problem for you.

Comment: Why is this task not done by filtering?

Comment: Interesting thought Variatus. I just never thought to do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your excessively long run times will be due to looping over 1048576 cells in your `For lngLoop = 1 To Rows.count` loop.  That can be improved by just processing as far as the last cell that contains data in the applicable column.

The problem of it not always working correctly is almost certainly due to the fact that you have some `Cells` references which aren't qualified with the sheet that you want to use, and therefore they refer to the `ActiveSheet`.

```
Sub GetDateRow_()
'//////Finds the row that has today's date and returns the value of that row to cell C34\\\\\\

    Dim SearchMe As Date
    Dim FindMe As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        SearchMe = .Range("C33").Value

        Set FindMe = .Range("C5:AD5").Find(What:=SearchMe, _
                                           LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                           LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                           SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                           MatchCase:=False, _
                                           SearchFormat:=False)
        If FindMe Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Date not found!"
        Else
            'I think this line
            '.Range("C34").Value = .Cells(1, FindMe.Column).Value
            'should be
            .Range("C34").Value = FindMe.Column
            'so that it saves the column number you want
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub CopyScheduledToList()
'//////Searches Today's day Column from the schedule given by GetDateRow Sub & assembles \\\\\\\
'//////      the names of those who are scheduled to work today to a list on Page 2      \\\\\\\

    Dim Ccount As Integer
    Dim lngLoop As Long
    Dim TodaysCol As Long
    Dim dShift As String
    Dim cShift As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet

    Ccount = 1
    dShift = "A63"
    cShift = "TLA"
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDst = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    TodaysCol = wsSrc.Range("C34").Value
    'Find last used row in today's column
    lastRow = wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, TodaysCol).End(xlUp).Row
    For lngLoop = 1 To lastRow
        If wsSrc.Cells(lngLoop, TodaysCol).Value = cShift Then 
            wsDst.Cells(1, "D").Value = wsSrc.Cells(lngLoop, "A").Value
        End If
'////// Get's the Team Leader and places name into column D on Page 2
        If wsSrc.Cells(lngLoop, TodaysCol).Value = dShift Then
            If wsSrc.Cells(lngLoop, "A").Value <> "" Then
                wsDst.Cells(Ccount, "A").Value = wsSrc.Cells(lngLoop, "A").Value
                Ccount = Ccount + 1
            End If
        End If
'////// Places the name from the working list onto page 2 and adds a count so the next value found
'////// will go to the next empty row on Sheet 2
    Next lngLoop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first sub is, in fact, a function (or should be) which returns a value which can be assigned to a variable in your second sub. The following code realises that concept. It is different in other respects too, but I think you will like it. Please try.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyScheduledToList()
    '//////Searches Today's day Column from the schedule given by GetDateRow Sub & assambles \\\\\\\
    '//////      the names of those who are scheduled to work today to a list on Page 2      \\\\\\\

    ' it is best practise, not to have any hard-coded addresses in the code.
    ' Therefore it is good to place all parameters separate from and before the code:
    Const SearchRow As Long = 5
    Const dShift As String = "A63"
    Const cShift As String = "TLA"

    Dim WsMain As Worksheet                     ' better to set your own variable
    Dim WsOutput As Worksheet                   ' even if it will be "ActiveSheet"
    Dim TgtColumn As Long
    Dim Rlast As Long                           ' last data row in WsMain
    Dim Rcount As Long                          ' output row counter
    Dim R As Long

    Set WsMain = ActiveSheet                    ' might be Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set WsOutput = Worksheets("Sheet2")         ' or, simply, Sheet1
    TgtColumn = DateColumn(WsMain, SearchRow)
    If TgtColumn < 1 Then Exit Sub

    Rcount = 1
    With WsMain
        Rlast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TgtColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        For R = 1 To Rlast
            Select Case .Cells(R, TgtColumn).value
                Case cShift
                    '////// Get's the Team Leader and places name into column D on WsOutput
                    WsOutput.Cells(Rcount, "D").value = .Cells(R, 1).value
                Case dShift
                    WsOutput.Cells(Rcount, "A").value = .Cells(R, 1).value
                Case Else
                    Exit Sub                    ' define the correct response if neither is found
            End Select
            If Len(WsOutput.Cells(Rcount, "A").value) Then Rcount = Rcount + 1
            '////// Places the name from the working list onto page 2 and adds a count so the next value found
            '////// will go to the next empty row on Sheet 2
        Next R
    End With
End Sub

Private Function DateColumn(Ws As Worksheet, _
                            ByVal SearchRow As Long) As Long
    ' returns the row that has today's date
    ' return 0 if not found

    Dim SearchMe As Variant
    Dim TgtDate As String
    Dim Fnd As Range

    If SearchRow < 1 Then Exit Function
    Do
        TgtDate = InputBox("Enter the target date", _
                           "List shift workers", _
                           Format(Date, "Short Date"))
        ' you can also set the default like Format(Date + 1, "d/m/yy")
        ' the sample date format must match your regional settings

        If IsDate(TgtDate) Then
            SearchMe = CDate(TgtDate)
            ' SearchMe will have the date in the format set
            ' in your regional settings
            Exit Do
        Else
            MsgBox "Please enter a valid date" & vbCr & _
                   "in d-m-yy format", vbExclamation, "Invalid date"
            ' adjust the required format to your regional settings
        End If
    Loop While Len(TgtDate)          ' enter blank or press Cancel to exit

    Set Fnd = Ws.Rows(SearchRow).Find(What:=SearchMe, _
                                 LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                 MatchCase:=False, _
                                 SearchFormat:=False)

     If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then DateColumn = Fnd.Column
End Function
```